# how to iterate value from this complex JSON object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have fetched data of "Orders" collection from Firebase firestore but i am unable to fetch specific value from that object ,code of fetching data from firebase is :

```
app.get('/trial',(req,res)=>{
  const ordersCollection = collection(db, 'Orders');
let ordersData
    // Fetch all documents from the collection
   const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const querySnapshot= await getDocs(ordersCollection);
         ordersData = [];

        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          // Store the data
          ordersData.push({ ...doc.data() });
        });
          ordersData.map((item,index)=>{
            console.log(item)
          })

       
        // console.log(ordersData,"orders")
       
     
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching documents: ', error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();

   

   
    res.send('ok')
})
```

i am receiving this response from the line "OrdersData.map function" :

```
{
  Orders: [
    {
      shipping_cost: null,
      currency_conversion: null,
      customer_email: null,
      success_url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
      payment_method_collection: 'if_required',
      status: 'complete',
      custom_text: [Object],
      submit_type: null,
      amount_total: 4600,
      shipping_options: [],
      currency: 'inr',
      subscription: null,
      customer: null,
      locale: null,
      created: 1696586174,
      shipping_address_collection: null,
      consent_collection: null,
      object: 'checkout.session',
      after_expiration: null,
      payment_status: 'paid',
      metadata: [Object],
      url: null,
      custom_fields: [],
      livemode: false,
      consent: null,
      id: 'cs_test_a1AyW6D94igWgrxBL8pBfj0l5pg7MbSa7AwqYtJSWyJkNmlfGJyJoe4ESs',
      payment_method_options: {},
      billing_address_collection: null,
      automatic_tax: [Object],
      mode: 'payment',
      payment_intent: 'pi_3NyAlxSH8i0IOWv312k6QJo3',
      expires_at: 1696672574,
      invoice_creation: [Object],
      allow_promotion_codes: null,
      invoice: null,
      amount_subtotal: 4600,
      payment_method_configuration_details: null,
      client_reference_id: null,
      payment_link: null,
      cancel_url: 'http://localhost:3000/cart',
      total_details: [Object],
      payment_method_types: [Array],
      recovered_from: null,
      setup_intent: null,
      customer_details: [Object],
      phone_number_collection: [Object],
      shipping_details: null,
      customer_creation: 'if_required'
    }
  ]
}
{}
{}
```

I have tried `ordersData.Orders.map` function but it is showing

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Then I tried

```
ordersData.map((item,index)=>{
            console.log(item.id)
          })
```

Output : undefined

Comment: it looks like `ordersData` is an array of three objects, the last two being empty objects

Comment: please remove all those `**` in the code, they make the code a little harder to read than it already is

Comment: yes i have removed ** & @JaromandaX how can i iterate it & get specific value ?

Comment: `ordersData[0].Orders.map` maybe, since only the first object in `ordersData` has anything in it

Comment: it is not working @JaromandaX

Comment: "not working" provides no information. Is there an error? or worse? I can't see the re-written code, perhaps you did something wrong

Comment: now it is working by 'ordersData[0].Orders.map' but i have many data in database i have to use a loop ,which loop should i use ? @JaromandaX

Comment: you have many data in database, but clearly only getting one record based on the data YOU say YOU got

Comment: i only entered one data for testing sir ,but there will be many order in this 'orderdata 'array after sometime  @JaromandaX

Comment: then you'll need to figure out the code - it's easy

Comment: okay Thankyou @JaromandaX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to format the `ordersData` array before using it. But if you really want to keep the `ordersData` array as is, then you can create a method like:

```js
const pluckOrderInfo = (key) =>
  ordersData.map((orderObj) => orderObj.Orders?.[0]?.[key]);

console.log(pluckOrderInfo("amount_subtotal"));
// [ 4600, undefined, undefined ]
```

Edit:

```js
const pluckValues = (data, key) =>
  data.map((orderObj) => orderObj.Orders?.[0]?.[key]);

console.log(pluckValues(ordersData, "amount_subtotal"));
// [ 4600, undefined, undefined ]
```

Comment: when i use above method i face this **error : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')** , and how can i format **OrdersData array**

Comment: @GautamParmar That's probably because you placed this method somewhere `ordersData` is not defined. To avoid such scenarios, you can pass `ordersData` as an argument to the method.

Comment: i have a **metadata** object too inside **Orders** array ,how can i fetch it ? itried it my using **metadata.UID** but is is showing me **Undefined** ,i have attached code in below comment

Comment: const pluckValuesFromAllOrders = (data, key) =>
      orders.flatMap((orderObj) =>
    orderObj.Orders?.map((order) => order[key]) || []
  );                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
       const orderDates = pluckValuesFromAllOrders(orders, 'metadata.UID');
        console.log(orderDates,'date')